# Сохранение состояния fragment Android java

Tags: java, android

Работаю с `BottomNavigationView`, подключил, создал отдельно `framgent`, переключается - все ок, но есть проблема : в самом `Fragment` все время вызываются методы `onCreateView` и `onViewCreated`, у меня там находится `RecyclerView` и данные беру с сервера и при переключении на этот `Fragment` создается ощущения лага, тк все обновляется и каждый раз запрашивается с сервера. Можно как-то сохранить состояние ? что бы не каждый раз эти методы вызывались или мб есть другой метод, который вызывается лишь раз при создании ?

В главном активити :

```
public Fragment getCalendarFr(String tag){
    CalendarCoachFragment fragmentDemo = (CalendarCoachFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragmentDemo == null) {
        return  CalendarCoachFragment.newInstance();
    }else{
        return  fragmentDemo;
    }
}


public Fragment getClientsFr(String tag){
    ClientsListCoachFragment fragmentDemo = (ClientsListCoachFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragmentDemo == null) {
        return  ClientsListCoachFragment.newInstance();
    }else{
        return  fragmentDemo;
    }
}
void settings(){
            BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =  new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_calendar:
                            openFragment(getCalendarFr("CALFR"), "CALFR");
                            return true;
                        case R.id.navigation_clients:
                            openFragment(getClientsFr("CLINTFR"), "CLINTFR");
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };
    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);


}

public void openFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment, tag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

пример Fragment

```
public static CalendarCoachFragment newInstance() {
    CalendarCoachFragment fragment = new CalendarCoachFragment();

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_calendar_coach, container, false);

    return view ;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.calendarRecyclerView);
    //to-do
}
```

Comment: Я думаю вам нужно посмотреть в сторону MVVM/MVP/MVI или прочих архитектурных паттернов. Таким образом вы сможете хранить состояние в классах модели и вам не нужно будет перезагружать данные при пересоздании фрагментов.

Comment: @Ziens скорее всего, вы правы, в качестве временно решения переделал все через hide/show

Comment: Hide/show - решает другую проблему, в отличии от архитектурных паттернов. В вашем случае, скорее всего, именно hide/show - верное решение, т.к. решает задачу лишнего рендера разметки каждый раз, что не очень решится добавлением архитектуры.